# Finding the electric field in a bar moving through a magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, equilibrium

In this diagram:

[image: A bar moving through an magnetic field]

I'm supposed to find the electric field through the bar at equilibrium. I know that at equilibrium, the accumulated positive charge on the bottom of the bar results in a field that prevents the magnetic force from moving any more positive charge down.

I've tried to solve the problem by simply setting the electric force equal to the magnetic force. I know the magnetic force points straight down, but since the charges are constrained to the bar, I've used only the component that points along the bar, or $qvB \sin \theta$. So, setting those equal, I obtain the equation $$qE = qvB \sin \theta$$, which yields $$E = vB \sin \theta$$ This sounds right to me - if $\theta$ is smaller than $\pi / 2$, then the electric field should be smaller as well.

However, the answer key says it should be just $E = vB$. How can I get away with ignoring the angle here?

Comment: $\theta$ in the equation for magnetic force is the angle between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{B}$. You used it as the angle at which the rod is inclined to the direction of velocity. The magnetic force is maximum as the charged rod or a net charge is moving perpendicular to the magnetic field. Now try to equate the two forces.

Comment: I do know that the rod's velocity is exactly perpendicular to the magnetic field. I do not think I'm mixing up the thetas. The theta in my equations is always the theta between the rod and the horizontal. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in the question. The theta factor that emerges is a result of taking only the component of the magnetic force that points along the rod.

Comment: the magnetic force depends not on  the alignment of charge along the direction of field, but through the angle between it's velocity and the field. Its perpendicular in your question. Then why are you trying to find the magnetic field component along the direction of rod. The charged rod can be considered as a net charge. However you place the rod, in this diagram, the magnetic field is perpendicular to the velocity of charge. The effect of the rod is just that it caries some charge. You don't need to bother about other details. Try to see the rod as a charge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion is coming from the fact that you are actually using theta for two different things here. Let's use phi for the angle between the velocity of the rod and the magnetic field, and use theta as it is depicted in the diagram. Then your expression should be written as
$$qvBsin\phi$$
This comes from the fact that $qvBsin\phi$ is derived from $q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$, using the identity that for any two vectors a and b
$$|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|=absin\phi$$
where phi is the angle between a and b. Since B is coming out of the page at every point and v is in the plane of the page, phi is always 90 degrees, and as you probably know, the sine of 90 degrees is 1. This should cause your final expression to reduce to the correct expression. It is important to realize that here the angle labeled in the figure as theta is not important to the expression.

Comment: Everything doesn't work out; see my comment on the question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am missing something, but you say that your final expression is E = vBsin(theta), but that the answer should be E = vB. You state that you know the rod's velocity is perpendicular to the magnetic field, so it sounds as though you are aware that theta is 90 here. Plugging 90 in causes your answer to reduce to the desired form of E = vB.

Comment: Theta in my answer is the angle between the rod and the horizontal.

Comment: I've edited my answer to try to better clarify what is happening. The angle between the rod and the horizontal is not important to the force from the rod moving through the field. Only the angle between the velocity and the field is important.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I'm not getting why the electric field doesn't get smaller as theta (in the diagram) gets smaller; doesn't it have to exert less force to counter the decreasing magnetic force?

Comment: The force is being exerted on every point in the rod regardless of its orientation. It might be helpful to view the rod as a collection of point charges. Each one will have a force exerted on it only dependent upon the direction with which it moves through the field (what the phi in my answer represents), the magnitude of the field, and the magnitude of its charge. It is irrelevant how close those charges are to the horizontal, which is what theta represents.